# Running an app off an external hard drive

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

Can I download [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/in/products/davinciresolve/) to an external hard drive and work from/off it?

My computer has a limited storage space, so I can not download it straight to my computer. Ideally, i'd like to download it to my external hard drive and work off it. Can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) How much empty space does your computer have? While it may be possible to run an app off of an external drive, the app may end up creating temporary files on your internal hard disk.

Comment: thanks for answering Nimesh. I have about 10gigs left on my computer. If it installed temporary files on my computer, once finished with my project, can i go to them [in my mac's library or where ever they are stored]  to then delete them?

Comment: The idea is, that it's quite possible to run an app from an external file (as long as it comes in a .app bundle). But while running, it may end up creating temporary files on the internal (root) drive. You need to have sufficient space for the temporary files and for the OS to function normally.

Comment: it comes in a .dmg file

Comment: sometime you need to address your drive storage issue.  Would you always have an external drive connected to your machine?  You can move a folder to an external drive and then use the unix ln command to point to the external folder.  This is a messy situation and should open a new thread to discuss solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Running is not a problem, but the program might (and, like many others, will) put several folders to ~/Library (hidden) folder - Logs, Cache, Container/Group Container. The size might be significant.